# Is it possible to force fail a rescue statement?

Tags: ruby

I'm cycling through several different attributes looking for something not set to `""`

To do this I wrote :

```
def email
  begin
    if email1 != ""
      email1 
    elsif email2 != ""
      email2
    elsif email3 != ""
      email3
    else
      Fail
    end
  rescue
    "Undefined"
  end
end
```

Basically, if it fails the logic on the first statement, I'd like it to be rescued.

Perhaps rescue isn't the right decision. What would you recommend?

Comment: It's hard to recommend something better without giving more details on your expected input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `def` is an implicit `begin`, so you can save yourself that. However, from your limited description, I think this should work for you:

```
[email1, email2, email3].reject(&:empty?).first || "undefined"
```

It either returns the first set email address or "undefined". My version reads a bit more like how you would describe the problem (take the first set email address or return "undefined"), mu's version is a bit more compact and probably what I'd use.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `rescue` to happen, you need to raise an exception -

```
def email
  begin
    raise StandardError if email1.empty?
  rescue StandardError
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: That said it rather seems like exceptions are being used for control flow here, which is generally not good practice.

Comment: Right, I agree Andrew. More so out of curiosity at this point. How do I force fail a statement to go to the next rescue

Comment: That's true. It's likely an `else` is the better solution here. Just wanted to answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps rescue isn't the right decision. What would you recommend?

You're right, `rescue` isn't the right decision; exceptions are for exceptional conditions, not for local flow control. I'd use [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
def email
  [email1, email2, email3, 'Undefined'].find { |s| !s.empty? } # or != '' if nils might be present
end
```

Or, if Rails (or part of it) was around, you could say this:

```
def email
  [email1, email2, email3, 'Undefined'].find(&:present?)
end
```